# fluentd is not able to connect aws elasticsearch from eks

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd, amazon-eks, aws-elasticsearch

I have installed a aws-es-proxy helm chart. I am using https://github.com/kokuwaio/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/fluentd-elasticsearch repo for created fluentd.
2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: unexpected error error_class=NoMethodError error="undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" 2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-4.1.0/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:464:in` detect_es_major_version'
2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-4.1.0/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:455:in `block in handle_last_seen_es_major_version' 2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-4.1.0/lib/fluent/plugin/elasticsearch_index_template.rb:35:in` retry_operate'
2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-4.1.0/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:454:in `handle_last_seen_es_major_version' 2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-4.1.0/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:312:in` configure'
2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.1/lib/fluent/plugin.rb:173:in `configure' 2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.1/lib/fluent/agent.rb:132:in` add_match'
2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.1/lib/fluent/agent.rb:74:in `block in configure' 2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.1/lib/fluent/agent.rb:64:in` each'
2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.1/lib/fluent/agent.rb:64:in `configure' 2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.1/lib/fluent/label.rb:31:in` configure'
2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.1/lib/fluent/root_agent.rb:143:in `block in configure' 2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.1/lib/fluent/root_agent.rb:143:in` each'
2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.1/lib/fluent/root_agent.rb:143:in `configure' 2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.1/lib/fluent/engine.rb:105:in` configure'
2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.1/lib/fluent/engine.rb:80:in `run_configure' 2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.1/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:602:in` block in run_worker'
2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.1/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:840:in `main_process' 2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.1/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:594:in` run_worker'
2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.1/lib/fluent/command/fluentd.rb:361:in `<top (required)>' 2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in` require'
2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require' 2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.11.1/bin/fluentd:8:in` <top (required)>'
2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/bin/fluentd:23:in `load' 2020-10-07 04:34:38 +0000 [error]: /usr/local/bundle/bin/fluentd:23:in` '`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to do this workshop in particular this step:
https://www.eksworkshop.com/intermediate/230_logging/ (EKS-logging fluetbit + elasticsearch + kibana)

I just tried this and found no problems.